# Trying to remove OpenLDAP: error trying to remove systemd which is protected

Tags: centos, yum, openldap

After `yum remove openldap` I get two errors:

> error trying to remove "systemd" which is protected

and

> error trying to remove "yum" which is protected

On the first, I found this: https://access.redhat.com/discussions/2091661
But I'm not sure I understand the answer.  And I also can't delete or rename `systemd.conf` in the folder `etc > yum > protected.d`

On the second, why is yum trying to remove itself?!?

Answer (score 1):

`openldap` is an indirect dependency of `yum` and `systemd`:

- `yum` requires rpm-libs
- rpm-libs requires `gnupg2`
- `gnupg2` requires `libldap-2.4.so.2` provided by `openldap`

so if you would remove `openldap`, `yum` would stop working...

Comment: Ok. thank you! So what is the correct way to rollback an install of openldap?

Comment: You cannot. You need it

Comment: (chuckle) Huh? I don't understand.  If I installed OpenLDAP with  'yum install -y openldap*', you're saying it's not possible to un-install it???!?!?

Comment: did installing of `openldap` remove another package? probably you can remove `openldap` if you install something else that provides what `gnupg2` needs...

Comment: openldap was certainly already there. So yum install -y openldap* did not install openldap. What was *probably* installed is `openldap-servers` which contains the slapd daemon.

Comment: oh man, I have no idea! I am very very new to both Linux and OpenLDAP.  I've been tasked with installing OpenLDAP, getting it working, and documenting the process.  It has litterally taken me all week to get the VM created, the GUI installed, OpenLDAP installed, and then OpenLDAP working. Now I just want to run throught he entire bloody process all over again by following by own documentation to see if I got it all right. I thought at least THAT would be a fast, easy process.  Silly me!!!

Comment: Well if you use a wildcard when installing packages, better write down what packages were actually installed. yum history  + yum history info XX can help.

Comment: ok, so if I only remove openldap-servers, should that get me back to a fresh install of OpenLdap? That's all I really want.

Comment: Correction, if I remove open-ldap servers and then reinstall open-ldap servers, should that get me back....

Comment: I'm not sure heh. I think RHEL/CentOS leaves configuration files around. you should list the contents and check what was left around and delete it (don't do that without verifying). One command to know the contents is rpm -ql